# Mysql: Toggle value of int field under two conditions for UPDATE query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

What I'm looking to do is insert a record, then deactivate previous records with the same ID because they will no longer be in use. However, I'm looking to do this in the simplest way possible. Deleting the record really isn't an option.

Attempted order of operations:

1. Insert with active inUse value `inUse = 1`
2. Update the following records for the same ID that are no longer in use: `inUse = 0`

My first thought was to run this query:

`UPDATE page_tags 
   SET inUse = IF(inUse = 1, 0, 1) 
   WHERE page_id = 23678459 
     AND tag_id NOT IN (10, 4);`

The only problem with this query is that if it's run again, it will toggle all of those deactivated values back to 1. I need all of the tags for the specific ID to only toggle back if they are being targeted by the WHERE statement.

Comment: You could do unconditional `update` of `inUse` to 0 as a first query then `insert` with `inUse=1`. Are there any reasons not to do it this way?

Comment: @ManieQ I thought about that, but either way I'd still think you'd need some way to watch it because if a tag already existed, I wouldn't add a new one, I'd use the existing. So I'd need to either not deactivate that tag, or reactivate it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@John P has a decent answer, however his answer requires the use of triggers. That to me seems to be more than needed to solve the problem at hand. The current working solution is:

Create an ***Unique Index*** on `page_tags.page_id` and `page_tags.tag_id`.

Update all rows where the ***page_id = 234234***:

```
UPDATE page_tags SET inUse = 0 WHERE page_id = 234234
```

Insert tags:

```
INSERT INTO page_tags (page_id, tag_id, inUse) VALUES (234234, 49343, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE inUse = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for trigger. Something like will perhaps do (pseudocode)?

**UPDATE for handling reuse of previuos tags:**

Do your insert/update:

```
INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

Then use two triggers, one for inserts and one for updates.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_inuse_insert BEFORE INSERT ON page_tags
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE page_tags SET inuse=0 WHERE page_id = NEW.page_id;
  END;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_inuse_update BEFORE UPDATE ON page_tags
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE page_tags SET inuse=0 WHERE page_id = NEW.page_id;
  END;
```

Comment: (Edited) John, thanks for the suggestion. The only problem here that I see is if a tag already exists, I'd like to activate it for reuse (inUse=1). No sense in adding a new row for duplicate tag ids

Comment: Ok, there is more to it than just "insert a record, then deactivate previous records with the same ID because they will no longer be in use" then?

Comment: Also part of the posted question was: "I need all of the tags for the specific ID to only toggle back if they are being targeted by the WHERE statement." So John, while this is certainly an appropriate answer, it's not the one I went for. The reason is because your answer requires triggers which seems to be more than needed.

Comment: Debugging can get a bit harder with triggers and one tends to forget their existence. Keeping it simple is a good aim. Glad you solved it.